# Any way to use a tuple as key in a shelf? (Python)

Tags: python, shelve

I want to use a tuple (1,2,3) as a key using the shelve module in Python.  I can do this with dictionaries:

```
d = {}
d[(1,2,3)] = 4
```

But if i try it with shelve:

```
s = shelve.open('myshelf')
s[(1,2,3)] = 4
```

I get: "TypeError: String or Integer object expected for key, tuple found"

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8):

How about using the repr() of the tuple:

```
s[repr((1,2,3))] = 4
```

Answer (score 7):

As per the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html?highlight=shelf#shelve.Shelf),

> the values **(not the keys!)** in a shelf
>   can be essentially arbitrary Python
>   objects

My emphasis: shelf keys must be strings, period. So, you need to turn your tuple into a str; depending on what you'll have in the tuple, `repr`, some `separator.join`, pickling, marshaling, etc, may be fruitfully employed for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Why not stick with dictionaries if you want to have arbitray keys ? The other option is to build a wrapper class around your tuple with a **repr** or **str** method to change it to a string. I am thinking of a library(natural response to shelves) - your tuple can be the elements in the [Dewey decimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dewey_decimal) and the **str** creates a concatenated complete representation.

Answer (score 1):

This may be an old question, but I had the same problem.

I often use shelve's and frequently want to use non-string keys. 
I subclassed shelve-modules class into a shelf which automatically converts non-string-keys into string-keys and returns them in original form when queried. 
It works well for Python's standard immutable objects: int, float, string, tuple, boolean.

It can be found in: https://github.com/North-Guard/simple_shelve