# Python: Best way to declare more than one keys in a shelf

Tags: python, format, readability

**Context:** I'm trying to practice shelves in python and wanted to make the most basic program to try out methods.

I wrote this code:

#creates a shelf, with 3 set keys and 3 input values then prints it

```
import shelve

settings_shelf = shelve.open('TempData')

settings_shelf['volume'] = input()
settings_shelf['graphics'] = input()
settings_shelf['auto-save'] = input()

print(list(settings_shelf.keys())+ list(" ") + list(settings_shelf.values()))

settings_shelf.close()
```

Is there a better way to format this? instead of having 3 lines for inputs?
I found this: [Any way to use a tuple as key in a shelf? (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482631/any-way-to-use-a-tuple-as-key-in-a-shelf-python) but I didn't really understand the answer..

I tried `settings_shelf['volume','graphics'] = input(),input()` but it throws out this error: even though it accepts the two inputs Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "C:\Users\Simone\dev\Automate The Boring Stuff with
> Python\shelves.py", line 5, in 
> settings_shelf['volume','graphics'] = input(),input()   File "C:\Users\Simone\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\shelve.py",
> line 125, in **setitem**
> self.dict[key.encode(self.keyencoding)] = f.getvalue() AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'

I tried adding print(tuple(xyz)) but still doesn't work.

**Also..** would it be possible to write something like settings_shelf[input() = input() ?
I tried this aswell but it messes up the end result it switches the last key and value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [shelve](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html) docs:

> The keys are ordinary strings.

So you need to convert tuple to string, and convert it back later if needed.

It't easier to use lists and `json` module

Here is the example:

```py
import json
import shelve

settings_shelf = shelve.open('TempData')

obj = {
    'volume': 123,
    'graphics': 456,
    'auto-save': True,
}

folder, name = 'some', 'obj'

# Convert list to string
obj_key = json.dumps([folder, name])
print(obj_key)
# => '["some", "obj"]'

settings_shelf[obj_key] = obj

print(settings_shelf[obj_key])
# => {'volume': 123, 'graphics': 456, 'auto-save': True}

# Convert string back to objects
folder, name = json.loads(obj_key)
print(folder, name)
# => 'some obj'
```

Comment: Thank you @Alex , I was wondering would it be possible to accept input() for a key?
So each time the program runs, you have to input the " settings " ?
Instead of having them prefixed to those 3 strings ?

Comment: It's possible, but it's better to split logic into multiple lines, for first, get key names and value names, and only then assign them to  `shelve`. Also don't forget to mark answer as acceptet if it helps you